# nginx emerg SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations

Tags: nginx

My /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default file:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name omp.kolebor.ru;

    location = / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location /  {
        try_files $uri /test/$uri /test/index.html;
    }

    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/omp.kolebor.ru/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/omp.kolebor.ru/privkey.pem;
    ssl_client_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/omp.kolebor.ru/ca2.crt;
    ssl_verify_client on;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = omp.kolebor.ru) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    server_name omp.kolebor.ru;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}
```

When i execute `"nginx -t"` i get an error:

> nginx: [emerg]
>   SSL_CTX_load_verify_locations("/etc/letsencrypt/live/omp.kolebor.ru/ca2.crt") failed (SSL:)

I checked several times the correctness of the path, and it is correct.

I don't understand Why there is no error in parentheses (SSL:???)

Maybe certificate `ca2.crt` is not incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

I try create new crt from command:

> openssl req -new -newkey rsa:1024 -nodes -keyout ca.key -x509 -days 500 -subj /C=RU/ST=Moscow/L=Moscow/O=company/OU=User/CN=etc/emailAddress=support@site.com -out ca.crt

and it worked with this certificate.